# How to show value of httpwebresponse(JSON) in MessageBox?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, response, fiddler

How to show value of httpwebresponse in MessageBox?
i created webreq in which response i am getting is a json.

```
{ "quiz": { "sport": { "q1": { "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?", "options": [ "New York Bulls", "Los Angeles Kings", "Golden State Warriros", "Huston Rocket" ], "answer": "Huston Rocket" } }, "maths": { "q1": { "question": "5 + 7 = ?", "options": [ "10", "11", "12", "13" ], "answer": "12" }, "q2": { "question": "12 - 8 = ?", "options": [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ], "answer": "4" } } } }
```

and i want to show this response in MessageBox
this is my c# code

```
        //Removed Main code
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;
        var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(responseText);
        }
```

when i try to show it shows like this some symbole
[Before Opening Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYY59.png)

and when i open fiddler and run C# code it shows correctly Why?
[After Opening Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvys0.png)
How to solve it?

Comment: `request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;`?

Comment: @john where to apply this ?

Comment: ...to your request, before you call `request.GetRequestStream()`. Assuming it's compression that's the problem.

Comment: @john Thanks A ton it worked :)
it was because response was compressed using GZip ??

Comment: Yes. I'll add an answer to that effect tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the website is using compression to serve your request, which Fiddler is removing.

You can ask the `HttpWebRequest` to automatically decompress the response for you:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

So your complete code would be:

```
//Removed Main code
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;
var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
{
    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(responseText);
}
```